# Change worksheet name with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change the name of some worksheet names , with values of one specific cell.
. For example , on sheet 1 i have my inputs, and on cell b3 i have the new name for sheet5, how do I create a code that give that change ?
thanks

Comment: sheet5.name = sheet1,range("b3")

Comment: @Jeeped, watch that comma!

Comment: There are so many examples of this. Please do your research before asking the question

Comment: @DisplayName, well ... you gotta leave **something** for them to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Name` property of worksheet object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-name-property-excel

Example:

```
ActiveSheet.Name = Range("D5").Value
```

Or

```
SomeSheet.Name = Range("D5").Value
```

Comment: I wouldn't advice anyone to use `ActiveSheet` as it fraught with danger. Also, I would suggest the you use a qualified sheet before  `Range`.. again, although it will work but it can cause problems

Comment: I was an example, but you're right, I've updated the answer @Zac